# Laravel, Using a cPanel shared hosting if possible?

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting with bluehost.com... can I just put my project on that.. like upload public files to public_html and others to root directory and backup MySQL DB and upload it to my shared hosting then edit my .env file... will this actually work with Laravel?

I searched most online resources and it requires ssh access to deploy, but the way I explained should not require that right?

I mean this way you don't have to go throw terminal access right?

I used to do that with WordPress when I want to set everything locally then upload it and edit URLs from the dashboard and stuff...

Comment: Yes you can do that as you said. It will work fine. But when you upload public files to public_html and other files to root directory. Then you have to link that directory with your public files, in index you will do some changes i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would work. 
But you have to ensure one thing that, in your cpanel your domain point to the `/public` folder of laravel project.
Normally cPanel points the http requests to `public_html` folder, but laravel start from its `public` folder. You can achieve this by two way.

1. By pointing your server to straight to `public` folder
2. Copying the `index.php` to the `public_html`, in that case you have to edit `index.php` to run the laravel project properly. And I don't recommend this step. Step 1 is lot more easier.

Comment: Ok, I tried doing method 2 but I ran into issue where it shows error sometimes of not finiding views
InvalidArgumentException
View [Success] not found. 
so I guess I am missing something..
btw how to do it using method 1 ? u mean by using htaccess?

Comment: Editing .htaccess would be easier solution, other you have to change document_root for your domain/sub-domain.
Did you replaced `../` as `./` in index.php?

Comment: Actually I was using capital in Success, I changed to success and it is working..

Comment: Why you don’t recommend the Method 2? I think method 1 is the right way to do it, but I find it very hard to accomplish. there's to many options and conf on so many distros

Comment: @absolutkarlos if you go by method 2, your site's sensitive Infos are not secure anymore. Try http://yoursite.com/.env , that also apply got your logs/cache basically everything of your laravel app.

Comment: thanks my friend, I did try to access those files, but I got 404, so I'm fine I think. Just to be clear, I want to setup the method 1, but it was a nightmare